# How to delete firebase database node from html table using javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nodes

I want to delete firebase realtime database from my html table. I used multiple nodes to store data in firebase database, here is my code

```
var database = firebase.database();
database.ref('app-data').on('value', function(snapshot){
    if(snapshot.exists()){
        var content = '';
        snapshot.forEach(function(data){
            var val = data.val();
            var childKey = data.key;
            content +='<tr>';
            
            content += '<td>' + val.desc + '</td>';
            content += '<td>' + "<input type='button' value='Delete' class='delete' onclick='delete_row("+childKey+")'>" + '</td>';

            content += '</tr>';
        });
        $('#todays_quote').append(content);
    }
});

function delete_row(childKey) {
  var dataRef = firebase.database.ref("app-data'").child(childKey);
  dataRef.remove()
  .then(function(){
    console.log("Remove succeeded.")
  })
  .catch(function(error){
    console.log("Remove Failed!"+error.message)
  });
}
```

Data successfully show in html table but I am not figure out how to add delete function, I want that when user click on specific delete button that time delete this data only, here are few database images

[image]

The below screenshot is my html table where the data is showing from the firebase database

[image]

Can anyone help me to implement this thing, thanks :)

Comment: What's the error, you are getting? Your implementation is right.

Comment: after click on delete button nothing happens

Comment: log says VM768 admin.html:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: MR5InceNGosnWyacrKo is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick (VM499 admin.html:1)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem on the string. Missing the quotes.

```
content += '<td>' + "<input type='button' value='Delete' class='delete' onclick=\"delete_row('"+childKey+"')\">" + '</td>';
```

The function should be called as `delete_row('YOUR ID')`.

Hope that works!

Comment: still nothing happens